# need help converting perl regex to python

Tags: python, regex, perl

I need to port some Perl code to python, and Im not very familiar with Perl..

```
if (($fieldsParsed==0)&(/\/\/ address,.*/)) {
                push (@reservedMemoryArray,$_);
                $fieldsParsed = 1;
            }
```

I need help understanding this regexp. what does the `/\/\/ address,.*/` mean? and if this regex matches, the next line is pushed into the array, right?

Thanks

Comment: The actual regex is `\/\/ address,.*`. `/` is most probably the delimiter, which is not needed in Python. I can't read Perl code, though, so I don't know what is happening in your code.

Comment: Quite human readable help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `/\/\/ address,.*/`:

```
/           : delimiter
\/\/        : two slashes
 address,   : literally ' address,'
.*          : any char 0 or more times
/           : delimiter
```

It returns true if the current `$_` contains `// address, whatever you want.....`

Comment: ah, ok. I was not aware of this delimiter syntax in Perl. If I just copy paste this regex into `re.match` I should remove those?

Comment: @WeaselFox: yes you should.

Comment: The outer slashes actually mark the match operator. As the doc says: "You can omit the m from m// if the delimiters are forward slashes, but for all other delimiters you must use the m prefix."